# Accessing Label inside a Row in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and labels inside rows of a table. To access the textbox I'm using
`data= $(this).find('#txtName').val();`

Now I'm not able to access the label in the same way. The label is rendered as
`<label for="Total">$65.00</label>`

How can I access the label's value and assign a value to it?

Comment: It would be nice to see your html structure.

Comment: Two months on the site and eight other questions, it's time to start formatting things correctly and reading the posted question to make sure vital information (like the markup of your `label`) isn't getting lost because you haven't formatted correctly. To the right when you were asking your question there was this handy **How to Format** box. Worth a read, as is [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area. Best,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to say when you haven't shown your HTML structure, but a couple of possibilities:

#### 1) The label is separate

If your label is separate, like this:

```
<tr>
<td><label for='txtName'>Some field</label></td>
<td><input type='text' id='txtName'></td>
</tr>
```

...then given the `id` of the textbox is `txtName`, you can use an [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to search for the label with that `for` attribute:

```
var label = this.find("label[for=txtName]"); // If the label is also within `this`
// or
var label = $("label[for=txtName]");         // Find it no matter where it is
```

**Edit**: So if the name of the field is `Total`, it would be:

```
var label = this.find("label[for=Total]"); // If the label is also within `this`
// or
var label = $("label[for=Total]");         // Find it no matter where it is
```

To set its contents (not "value"), use either `text` or `html`:

```
label.text("Field name");
label.html("Field <em>name</em>");
```

#### 2) The textbox is *within* the label:

**Edit**: Now that Drackir has fixed the formatting of your post, we can see that you're using the `for` attribute as above. Keeping this second part in case someone else sees this and is doing it this way.

If the textbox is within the label, like this:

```
<tr>
<td>
<label>Some field: <input type='text' id='txtName'></label>
</td>
</tr>
```

...then if `$(this).find('#txtName').val();` works, this should work:

```
var textBox = $(this).find('#txtName');
var label = textBox.parents('label');
// Do something with `textBox.val()` and `label`
```

*(If the textbox really is an immediate child of the label, you could use `.parent()` instead of `.parents('label')`, but the latter is useful if the text box is a descendant rather than an immediate child.)*

Once you have the `label`, you can't just set its content via `text` or `html` because you'll wipe out the field (since it's inside the label). You could do this:

```
var textBox = $(this).find('#txtName');
var label = textBox.parents('label');
textBox.detach(); // temporarily remove from the DOM
label.text("Field name: ");
textBox.appendTo(label);
```

That temporarily removes the text box for safekeeping (`detach` leaves event handlers in place), sets the text of the label to "Field name: ", and then appends the textbox back to it.

More:

- [`Selectors`](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
- [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [`parents`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [`parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [Traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)
- [`detach`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

Comment: +1 OP forgot the code tags but your first idea should solve the problem. And I've fixed the OPs post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get label value by `$("#yourlabelid").text()` and set its value by `$("#yourlabelid").text(value)`

Comment: 1. It's rare that you want to access a label by `id`. 2. If you did, it would be `$("#yourlabelid")`, not `$("yourlabelid")`.